# Selecting data from another SQL table to add to string text

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

the following code selects 3 random items(photos) with prices and passes it to my website as a string..

```
    SELECT TOP 3 
    thisweeksDate
    ,'<br/><a href="catalog/images/' 
                 + [filename] + 
                 '"    class="nyroModal" rel="gal" title="' 
                 + [price] + 
                 '" ><img   src="catalog/images/thumbnails/' 
                  + [filename] + 
                  + '" /></a>' 
                  + [price] 
     as strText
    ,fileID
    FROM [OCBUser].[tblItems]
    WHERE thisweeksDate = @thisweeksDate and price <> ''
    ORDER BY NEWID()
```

The above works perfectly but I don't know enough SQL yet to do the following..

**I need it to also select**

```
    friendlyOrderID from [OCBUser].[tblOrders] 
    where [OCBUser].[tblItems].accountID = [OCBUser].[tblOrders].accountID
```

and add it to the strText with a hyperlink prefix so it can be clicked on. So it would need to inclide something like...

`<a href="www.mysite.com/' + [friendlyorderID] + '"`

Any ideas ?

Many Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to use JOIN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a join

```
  SELECT TOP 3 thisweeksDate, '<br/><a href="catalog/images/' + [filename] + '"    class="nyroModal" rel="gal" title="' + [price] + '" ><img   src="catalog/images/thumbnails/' + [filename] + '" /></a>' + [price] as strText, fileID
  ,'<a href="www.mysite.com/' + [friendlyorderID] + '">link</a>'

  FROM [OCBUser].[tblItems]
  JOIN [OCBUser].[tblOrders] on [OCBUser].[tblItems].accountID = [OCBUser].[tblOrders].accountID 
  WHERE thisweeksDate = @thisweeksDate and price <> ''
  ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply.. It looks like it's going to work.. I'm just learning from the code a developer made for me.. Not used Joins myself yet but I see how that works now thank you. However I'm getting the following error I think because thisweeksdate exists in both [OCBUser].[tblOrders] and [OCBUser].[tblItems].. I need it to select from [OCBUser].[tblItems] Here's the error.....


    Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Rummage, Line 13
    Ambiguous column name 'thisweeksDate'.
    Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Rummage, Line 8
    Ambiguous column name 'thisweeksDate'.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.

Comment: It's ok, I sussed it.. I added the square bracket thing: WHERE [OCB].[tblItems].[thisweeksDate] = @thisweeksDate and price <> ''